# Angular 4 Router ':any/component'

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to angular4. I am trying to route. My problem is component there is dynamic appName will come Like the following one.

```
localhost:4200/dynamic-name/login.
```

Here I need to check if the dynamic name present on some services before hitting any component. Which means I need to check it on router module before going to the page. if there is present allow the router got to the login component. Otherwise, redirect to some default component. And I need to keep this dynamic-name all over the route link if exist.

please guide me anyone.

Comment: search for angular router guard

Answer (score 0):

You can set APP_BASE_HREF dynamically.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './';
import { getBaseLocation } from './service/baselocation.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: getBaseLocation
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in ./service/baselocation.service,

```
export function getBaseLocation() {
     var basePath = "your dynamical base path" //add logic to get your base path
    return '/' + basePath;
}
```

---

And Another way is to let the user to hit "/logn" route, then use AuthGuard to redirect to dynamic login route.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    var path=YourPathService.getPath();

     this.router.navigate(['/' + path + '/login']);

     return false;

  }
}

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'path1/login', Path1LoginComponent },
  {path: 'path2/login', Path1LoginComponent }
];
```

Comment: Is this only to keep the dynamic name on a route?

Comment: I need to check  the dynamic name before going to the route